# How to compare two downcasted object types in C++

Tags: c++

I have two objects inheriting from Base class.
Both are stored in vector:

```
std::vector<Base*> m_vector;
```

How can I check if the first type of object is equal to the second type of object?

Scenarios:

1.

- First object type: `A : public Base`
- Second object type: `B : public Base`
- Result: Not equal

2. 

- First object type: `A : public Base`
- Second object type: `A : public Base`
- Result: Equal

3. 

- First object type: `A : public Base`
- Second object type: `B : public A`
- Result: Not equal

Comment: are there only two derived classes or more? How is 1 different from 3 ?

Comment: You could give the base type a pure virtual "type()" function that all derived classes must implement. Then compare based on what `type()` returns..

Comment: You can't have `class B: public Base {};` and `class B: public A {};` at the same time.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to compare the types of the objects, not the objects themselves? If so then that would simply be `typeid(*a) == typeid(*b)` assuming your types are polymorphic.

Comment: If you don't want to write additional "compare" or "type" methods, you can just use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid and compare `name` or `index` of your types (for it to work, then need to be polymorphic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am simplifying things a lot to get a point across. You have a

```
std::vector<Base*> m_vector;
```

This basically means: You have a vector of pointers to `B`. The actual objects are polymorphic, meaning you don't care what the actual type is as long as they inherit from `B`.

Now you want to do something that requires you to know the actual type of the elements.

Thats a contradiction.

The easiest way to solve that contradiction is to give up the second point: Don't care what the actual type is, use only the interface defined in the base class.

One way to do that is to use `typeid`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
    bool same_type(const Base& other) {
        return typeid(*this) == typeid(other);
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct A : Base {};
struct B : Base {};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> x;
    x.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>());
    x.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    x.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>());
    
    std::cout << "expect 0 : " << (x[0]->same_type(*x[1])) << "\n";
    std::cout << "expect 1 : " << (x[1]->same_type(*x[2])) << "\n";
}
```

For details on `typeid` I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid.

As suggested in a comment, you don't actually need to write a `Base::same_type()` but you can use `typeid` directly.

Comment: The names are not guaranteed to be unique, but why not just compare the `std::type_info` objects that `typeid` returns?

Comment: @John they are not? Oh, then I learned something today. Returning `typeid` was an error, let me check again...

Comment: Not according to cppreference.

Comment: @john I dont get why I cannot delete my own answer when it is accepted. I mean generally we trust in OP being able to decide which answer to accept, but when the answer is wrong, OP would need to know the right answer to see that, then they wouldnt have asked the question in the first place :/

Comment: It's news to me that you cannot delete an accepted answer. But you can edit it presumably.

Comment: @john I'd dont understand why returning `typeid(*this)` didnt work ("calling private constructor"), but I found a different fix.